# How do I extrude a face to a single vertex

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender so I am trying to learn the basics so bear with me while I try to explain this. I am trying to extrude a face to a single point to make a spikey-looking shape and I only seem to be able to extrude the face outwards keeping the face the same size but I actually want the face to extrude to a point or vertex.
[image: The object that has been extruded incorrectly]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to use *Vertices > Merge* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) *> Collapse* to turn multiple selected faces into multiple vertices:

[image]

> **Collapse**
>
> Every island of selected vertices (connected by selected edges) will merge on its own median center, leaving one vertex per island.

[Merging vertices](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merging-vertices)

Comment: I'm upvoting this post because the GIF is so satisfying to watch!

Answer (score 4):

you can extrude the faces and then scale them, you can change your pivot point to individual origin so that you scale the faces individually.

[image]

Comment: ...and then "remove doubles" to merge the overlapping vertices.